# Compile a WPF application from a source file using C#?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I recently created an application in WPF.
I want to be able to change the application Logo, The Form title and make other customizations from a Builder (winforms app) that compiles the WPF application from source file to Executable

Could someone please **show a code example** on how can I compile a WPF application using C# ? I know how to compile a `.cs` source file using `CSharpCodeProvider` but is it possible to use the CodeProvider to compile a WPF from source file ?

Anyhelp would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for examples using csc.exe that's included in the .NET Framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a look at [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{
    string workingDirectoryPath = "PathToYourSolutionFile"
    string resultsFileMarker = workingDirectoryPath + @"\DotNetBuildResult.txt";

    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"YourSolutionName.sln /nologo /fileLogger /fileloggerparameters:errorsonly;LogFile=""" + resultsFileMarker + @""" /noconsolelogger /t:clean;rebuild /verbosity:normal /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86";
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectoryPath;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
    process.Dispose();

    using (StreamReader resultsStreamReader = new FileInfo(resultsFileMarker).OpenText())
    {
        results = resultsStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    if (results.Trim().Length != 0)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(resultsFileMarker);
        errorEncountered = true;
        throw new Exception("Error were errors rebuilding the .Net WPF app - please check the log file that has just opened.");
    }
}
```

Comment: where can i find the generated exe ?

Comment: It will be in the Bin/Release folder of where you solution file is located.

Comment: the code executes but nothing happens ?! I can't see the file in the release folder

Comment: You need to make sure that you have set `string workingDirectoryPath = "PathToYourSolutionFile"`, where `"PathToYourSolutionFile"` is the actual path of where your solution file is located. This is very important.